# Proxmox additional Ip with Port Forwarding

Tags: proxmox

As you see in this configuration i attach vmbr0 to my local area clients and get 192.168.0.x ip and then go internet with eth0 (MASQUERADE and POSTROUTING ). eth0 my main ip its 78.xxx.xxx.178. Whenever a local area want to go internet then its getting my main ip for internet usage. Whenever i want to RDP access to my local area clients i have setup this rules

( iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 7002 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.5:3389)

With this i can RDP to my 192.168.0.5 client from outside 78.xxx.xxx.178:7002.

My question is so simple How Can i do this with my other additional ips ? I cant configure it.

For example i want to rdp my client (192.168.0.10) with 188.xxx.xxx.xx1 not with main ip.

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet
static address 78.xxx.xxx.178
netmask 255.255.255.255
gateway 78.xxx.xxx.161
pointopoint 78.xxx.xxx.161

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0
inet static address 78.xxx.xxx.178
netmask 255.255.255.255
bridge_ports none
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
bridge_maxwait 0

ADDITIONAL IPs

up ip route add 188.xxx.xxx.xx1/32 dev vmbr0
up ip route add 188.xxx.xxx.xx2 32 dev vmbr0
up ip route add 188.xxx.xx3/32 dev vmbr0

iface eth0
inet6 static address 2a01:4f8:100:92a7::2
netmask 64
gateway fe80::1

## localarea for internet usage.

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static address 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
bridge_ports none
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0

## IPTABLES

post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.0.0/24' -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '192.168.0.0/24' -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

## RDP

post-up iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 7002 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.5:3389
post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 7002 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.5:3389

Answer (score 1):

Leave eth0 on manual and use VMBR0 for all your public IPs. I have a similiar setup.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug eth0

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address  199.168.xxx.xxx
        netmask  255.255.255.248
        gateway  199.168.xxx.xxx
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
```

That will keep you from losing your web interface, but will still permit you to use the additional IPs on the VMBR0 interface without an issue. You can keep the rest of the config the same for VMBR1, it should not affect it.